# How can I dynamically change the email subject using Log4J SMTPAppender?

Tags: java, log4j

```
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.SMTPHost=www.company.com
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.To=email.address1@company.com,email.address2@company.com,email.address3@company.com
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.From=some.emailaddress.com
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.Subject=messagesubject1
```

I am using the above mentioned log4j property file to send 
email when I do

```
log.error("Error message");
```

How do I be able to make it dynamic so that 
the message subject can change dynamically depending upon the machine name(env name).

eg:

```
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.Subject=messagesubject1, messagesubject2, messagesubject3
```

I want to use subjects 1,2 and 3 dynamically depending upon machine name.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following piece of code I read out the *log4j.properties* file, set the property **log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.Subject** to **emailRecipients** and reset the log4j configuration. Could be done at the start of the application, you just need to set the *emailRecepients* string right.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
         InputStream configStream = Thread.class.getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties");
         if (configStream == null) {
             throw new RuntimeException();
         }
         props.load(configStream);
         configStream.close();
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Cannot load log4j configuration file ");
    }

    props.setProperty("log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.Subject", emailRecipients);

    LogManager.resetConfiguration();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Comment: What about the message that gets generated dynamically inside the code.I want to capture that. Is there a way.

Answer (score 5):

You should just need to make use of the hostname variable something like:

```
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.Subject=${hostname}
```

Depending on your paritcular configuration and OS you may need to supply this variable to your JVM at statrup using -Dhostname='machinename' or -Dhostname=$HOST

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 solutions:

1. Write your own logger that will use SMTPAppender and set the properties programatically.
2. Use the [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) to put a dynamic value in your code.  You can get values from the MDC in your log4j.xml with the `%X`.

ex:

```
log4j.appender.ERROREMAIL.Subject=%X{key}
```

Comment: I am working on your suggestion no. 1. I was able to change subject but how do I set the message . can I have some link or examples.

Comment: My impression was that when you call logger.error("this is my error") the String "This is my error" would appear in the message content!  After some reflection, solution 2 would be easier since you don't have to code anything.  Is your App a Web app or a stand alone application?

Answer (score 1):

To set a username or over ENV variable

```
log4j.appender.smtp.Subject=SYNC PROJECTS (${user.name}) Error Log ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Initial Logging configuration
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>


    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>


    <!-- BufferSize almacena un buffer de mensajes. Un evento de tipo error o 
    superior provoca el envio del correo junto con el resto de mensajes en el buffer (si los hay) -->
    <appender name="emailAppender"  class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">  

        <param name="BufferSize"    value="40"/> 
        <param name="SMTPHost"      value="conectores.mydomain.es" />  
        <param name="SMTPUsername"  value="weblogic" />           
        <param name="From"          value="no.reply@mydomain.es" />  
        <param name="To"            value="foo.bar@externos-mydomain.es" />  
        <param name="Subject"       value="Notificación de la aplicación" />  

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%n%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] [%l] %n%m%n" />  
        </layout>  
    </appender>  

    <!-- Las trazas de nivel trace o superior las mete en el buffer, el resto las desecha -->
    <logger name="smtp.logger">  
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="emailAppender" />  
    </logger>   

    <root>
        <priority value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Dynamic configuration of SMTAppender attributes
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package es.foo.test;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender;

public class TestSMTPAppender {

    private static Logger smtp = Logger.getLogger("smtp.logger");
    private static boolean ini_flag = false;    
    private static final Properties propiedades = new Properties(); 
    static {
        try {           
            propiedades.load(TestSMTPAppender.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mydomainUtiles.properties"));
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            System.err.println("error while creating properties from 'mydomainUtiles.properties': " + ioe.getMessage());    
        }
    }   

    private static void initializeLogger(){ 

        String SMTPHost = propiedades.getProperty("host");
        String SMTPUsername = propiedades.getProperty("user");
        String From = propiedades.getProperty("sender");

        Enumeration eappenders = smtp.getAllAppenders();
        while(eappenders.hasMoreElements()){
            Appender appender = (Appender) eappenders.nextElement();
            if(appender instanceof SMTPAppender){

                if(SMTPHost != null){
                    ((SMTPAppender)appender).setSMTPHost(SMTPHost);
                }

                if(SMTPUsername != null){
                    ((SMTPAppender)appender).setSMTPUsername(SMTPUsername);
                }

                if(From != null){
                    ((SMTPAppender)appender).setFrom(From);
                }

                // Place here other attributes, like Subject

                ((SMTPAppender)appender).activateOptions();
            }           
        }
    }

    public static Logger getSMTPLogger(){
        if(!ini_flag){
            initializeLogger();
            ini_flag = true;        
        }
        return TestSMTPAppender.smtp;
    }   

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TEST
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package es.foo.test;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender;

public class Test {

    private static Logger smtp = TestSMTPAppender.getSMTPLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        smtp.trace("message1");
        smtp.debug("message2");
        smtp.info("message3");
        smtp.warn("message4");
        smtp.error("message5");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if we are reading the properties and adding the subject throw java code we will get concurrent request problem.

if first user modified the subject and doing some other operations before sending the mail. at the same time second user added different subject. first user is also get the second user's subject.